# Correct positioning of a node and a circuitikz component

Tags: positioning, circuitikz, anchor

I would like to mix "conventional" tikz `node` and `circuitikz` components in the same `tikzpicture` but I have problem with positioning them.

For example, I would like to obtain this result:

[image]

But with the MWE below I obtain this result (the node is overlapping the battery component):

[image]

How can I avoid the overlap of the node and the battery without manual increase of the distance between them?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to [battery1={bat}, name=bat] ++(0.5,0)%
        (bat.east) -- ++(0.5,0)%
        node[rectangle,draw] (Nod1) {Node 1}%
        ;%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `node[anchor=west,rectangle,draw] (Nod1) {Node 1}`

Comment: It works like a charm thanks a lot (I'm so silly) ! Do you want to put your comment into an answer ?

Comment: Notice also that `anchor=west` is the same as `right` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to specify an anchor for the node, the default (which you have) is `anchor=center`, but you need `anchor=west`.

**Update:** following Zarko's comment I provide another option removing the `east` anchor in the battery and changing the distance.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to [battery1={bat}, name=bat] ++(0.5,0)%
        (bat.east) -- ++(0.5,0)%
        node[anchor=west,rectangle,draw] (Nod1) {Node 1};
%%%%%%% Or better (See Zarko and Romano's comments):
        \draw (0,-2) to [battery1=bat, name=bat2] ++(0.96,0) node[anchor=west,draw] (Nod1) {Node 1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but to my opinion `(bat.east)`  is superfluous. Code can be simple `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [battery1=bat] ++(0.5,0)%
            -- ++ (0.5,0) 
            node[right,draw] (Nod1) {Node 1}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Zarko, you're right but it changes the distance. I left it there because that. If the circuit is more complex I don't want to change anything

Comment: Juan Castaño (+1),  I understand your reasons, but @Zarko has a point — the `(bat.east)` move the current point back a bit, so there is part of the wire which is double-stroke; it's not a big problem but can create antialiasing artifacts in some viewer.

Comment: @Romano, corrected. I wasn't aware of that, so thanks for pointing it!!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Is it possible to make Tikz calculate this "changing in the distance" (in order to avoid double-strokeed wire) in order to not have to manually write `++(0.96...`? Or, is it possible to draw the battery symbol without any wire after it? Please tell me if you think this questions need a dedicated TeX.SE question.

Comment: @SylvainRigal, I think there is no need for that. I put 0.96 to approximate the original distance you used. But you can specify whatever distance you need. If you write there `++(1...` you won't see many changes

Comment: Ok I got it thanks!